# mysql filter duplicates where other column matches

Tags: mysql

I am currently stuck with a homework exercise...

We are using the sakila db (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/)

The exercise is to find and select every film in which more than one actor has the same first name and select these actors

e.g.

```
title             vn       nn
AFRICAN EGG       MATTHEW  TAUTOU
AFRICAN EGG       MATTHEW  LEIGH 
ANALYZE HOOSIERS  TOM      MCKELLEN  
ANALYZE HOOSIERS  TOM      MIRANDA
```

I currently using 3 tables for that (tables -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila-structure-tables.html):

- film_actor
- actor
- film

I currently select every actor who is in a film which has more than 1 actor with the same first name with this:

```
SELECT f.title title, a.actor_id, a.first_name vn, a.last_name nn FROM film_actor fa
LEFT JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film f ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
WHERE fa.film_id IN
(
    SELECT fa.film_id FROM film_actor fa
    LEFT JOIN actor a ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
    LEFT JOIN film f ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
    GROUP BY a.first_name, f.title HAVING count(a.first_name) > 1
)
ORDER BY title;
```

I get this as a result:

```
title                   actor_id vn     nn
DESPERATE TRAINSPOTTING 117      RENEE  TRACY
DESPERATE TRAINSPOTTING 137      MORGAN WILLIAMS
DESPERATE TRAINSPOTTING 187      RENEE  BALL
DESPERATE TRAINSPOTTING 77       CARY   MCCONAUGHEY
```

I have no idea how to get only the names of the duplicate actors...
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT(DISTINCT firstname)`:

```
SELECT f.title title, a.actor_id, a.first_name vn, a.last_name nn
FROM film_actor fa
LEFT JOIN actor a
    ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
LEFT JOIN film f
    ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT a.first_name, fa.film_id
    FROM film_actor fa
    LEFT JOIN actor a
        ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
    WHERE fa.film_id IN
    (
        SELECT fa.film_id
        FROM film_actor fa
        LEFT JOIN actor a
            ON a.actor_id = fa.actor_id
        LEFT JOIN film f
            ON f.film_id = fa.film_id
        GROUP BY fa.film_id
        HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.first_name) > 1
    )
    GROUP BY a.first_name, fa.film_id
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
) t
    ON a.first_name = t.first_name AND
       fa.film_id   = t.film_id
```

In your original attempt, you were checking the count of *all* first names.  This would of course then be true for any movie having more than one actor.  Instead, you want to check the count of distinct actors.

Comment: this one returns 5441 rows.

My subquery returns just the movies which have duplicate actor first names (I am not sure if this is the way it should be made but I checked it and it seems to be right).

Comment: Your original subquery has a problem.  What output do you actually want in the result set?  If you just want movies, take my subquery.  If you want the full cast, then use my full query.

Comment: I want the movies which have actors with the same first name and also these actors, (it is in my question, (under e.g.))

Comment: Aha!  You only want the duplicate actors.

Comment: with the same first name yes.
But only if they are in the same film

Comment: My query now might already meet your requirements.  I will update again to include more information.

Comment: I have just tried it. It returns  0 rows. :(
You can find the sakila db under examples here if you need it https://dev.mysql.com/doc/index-other.html

Comment: Wait...I had a typo in there...it should be `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` in all places.  Please try again.

Comment: WOW. Seems to work, thanks man.
It will sure take some time for me to understand this, but thanks for you help :)

Comment: My advice: Break down the query into smaller pieces.  Once you understand how each piece works, the whole query will suddenly start making sense.

Comment: just to make sure that I am right: the part after "WHERE fa.film_id IN" (in the () ) returns every film which has more than one actor in general?

Comment: @Th120 Yes this is correct.  But then the trick is next getting all actor, film pairs where the actor name appeared twice.  Finally, join this second result back to your original outer query and you are done.